# How to fix the spaces of superscript text

Tags: spacing, macros, superscripts

I'm trying to typeset an old bible which has all the verses superscripted. I created a command that produces a superscript number corresponding to the verse number, and then this is increased by one.

The problem is that there's a LOT of space before and after the verse number. I've been trying to adjust the space after the verse number using `\hspace`, but no luck so far.

Here there is the minimal working example with the desired and undesired outputs (please ignore other format details, suchs as chapters format):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twocolumn,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\newlength{\vl}
\newcounter{Verso}
\newcounter{Cap}
\setcounter{Verso}{1}
\setcounter{Cap}{1}

\newcommand{\vs}{%
\settowidth{\vl}{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}}
\noindent\textsuperscript{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}} %I used \hspace here with no luck
\stepcounter{Verso} 
}%

\newcommand{\ch}{%
\arabic{Cap}
\stepcounter{Cap}
\setcounter{Verso}{1}
}%

\newcommand{\cm}[1]{\flqq#1\frqq}

\begin{document}
\part{Génesis}
\chapter{\protect\ch}
\section{Desired output}
\textsuperscript{\tiny{1}}En el principio Dios creó los cielos y la tierra. \textsuperscript{\tiny{2}}La tierra era caos y confusión y oscuridad por encima del abismo, y un viento de Dios 
aleteaba por encima de las aguas.

\textsuperscript{\tiny{3}}Dijo Dios: \cm{¡Haya luz!}, y hubo luz. \textsuperscript{\tiny{3}}Vio Dios que la luz estaba bien, y apartó Dios la luz de la oscuridad; \textsuperscript{\tiny{3}}y llamó Dios a la 
luz \cm{día}, y a la oscuridad la llamó \cm{noche}. Y atardeció y amaneció: día primero.

\section{Real output: using vs command}

\vs{}Dijo Dios: \cm{Haya un firmamento por en medio de las aguas, que las aparte unas de otras.} \vs{}E hizo Dios el firmamento; y apartó las aguas 
de 
por debajo del firmamento, de las aguas de por encima del firmamento. Y así fue. \vs{}Y llamo Dios al firmamento \cm{cielos}. Y atardeció y amaneció: 
día segundo.
\end{document}
```

How should I modify the `\vs` command in order to achieve the desired output?

Best,

C.

Comment: The use of counters here isn't causing the space but is very weird. It is far more normal to increment counters before printing the number, using `\refstepcounter` but in the case of `\chapter` etc it numbers automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\newcommand{\vs}{%
\settowidth{\vl}{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}}
\noindent\textsuperscript{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}} %I used \hspace here with no luck
\stepcounter{Verso} 
}
```

add three word-spaces to the document each time it is used

Compare with

```
\newcommand{\vs}{%
\settowidth{\vl}{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}}X%
\noindent\textsuperscript{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}}X%I used \hspace here with no luck
\stepcounter{Verso}X%
}%
```

Which adds three `X`

You want

```
\newcommand{\vs}{%
\settowidth{\vl}{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}}%
\noindent\textsuperscript{\tiny{\arabic{Verso}}}%I used \hspace here with no luck
\stepcounter{Verso}%
}%
```

and similarly hide the ends of lines in the other macros.